# Installing a single dev package with Composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I have  `minimum-stability: stable` in my `composer.json`, but I need to install the dev version of one of the packages.

How can I force Composer to install the dev version only of that package?

Just to be clear. I want to install Yii2 2.0.x-dev (instead of `2.0.4`, which is the latest stable version).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enforce specific stability with `@`

```
2.0.x-dev@dev
```

You can find some example in the [Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links)